# Automating an aspx webpage with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a little work project I'm trying to solve.  It involves automating data entry into a web-based database (ASP page).  Part of the data entry requires clicking on a button to show a form.  The button makes a call to WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions().  I've been looking into trying to simulate the form POST using Javascript, but I am getting the impression it's a difficult thing to pull off, as I see that you need to supply the hidden VIEWSTATE data in the post, which just seems like a lot of work for little gain.

Anyway, I'm strictly limited to using IE 8, client-side scripting, and no external libs.  There is no API or provision for automated access to the web database.  The environment is totally Windows, and I do have .NET available.  At this point, it seems the only viable option is to try to use a .NET WebBrowser object from javascript.

Are there any other ways of going about this?

Comment: you can't use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use [xDomainRequests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to post the data to the ASP page, and then handle it there? It's pretty much the same thing as ajax, except some versions of IE (8 included) don't support ajax.

Comment: Haven't come across that one.  Not sure how that offers an advantage over XmlHttpRequest (which I've used successfully to access the page).